# Hosting wordpress blog on separate server and not mix it with rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, amazon-web-services, nginx

So we have our web app built on rails hosting on AWS and now we would like to add a **wordpress** blog which would have an address like this: http://www.website.com/blog.

The end goal is to not have the wordpress deployed along with or within our rails application code, to ensure maximum security for our application/data and performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Application Load Balancer.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html

Comment: can you please explain more ?